# Тормозит DBGrid1 в связке со вторым DBGrid2

Tags: c++builder, dbgrid

Два DBGrid в первый выборка происходит 1 раз через Select. Во второй DBGrid выборка происходит при изменении положение курсора в первом DBGrid, также Select.

```
SELECT*from Image_object_date Where (id_object=:id_object) ORDER BY id_imag DESC
```

Выборку осуществляю через IBDataSet, БД Firebird 2.0.

При перелистывании в первом DBGrid идут ппц какие тормоза, а во втором нет тормозов вообще. Но если выключить выборку во втором DBGrid первый престает тормозить.

Время выборки во второй DBGrid не превышает 350ms.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно обойти эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Вывел выполнение запроса в отдельный поток.
2)  Поставил задержку в самом потоке.
3)  И ввел условие при котором выполняется запрос выборки
Итог все тормоза ушли, но из за задержки есть небольшое ощущение что приложение тупит. Но это заметил только я, пользователи этого не увидели пока я им сам не указал на это.